# SQL CROSS TAB & PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, crosstab

I am using the following query to retrieve some results

```
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar, TS.StaffID) + CHAR(13) 
        + SUBSTRING ( TS.GivenName, 1 , 1 ) + '.' + CHAR(13) 
        + TS.Surname AS EmployeeInfo, SH.Hours,ts.UnitID,sh.RowID
         FROM dbo.tbl_TimesheetStaff AS TS
         Left OUTER JOIN
         dbo.tbl_StaffHours AS SH ON
         SH.ActivityUnitID = TS.ActivityUnitID
         AND Sh.StaffID=ts.StaffID
         WHERE TS.UnitID=1
```

The resulting set looks like

```
   EmployeeInfo   Hours  UnitID RowID
    114 H. Bar     73.71    111   401
    114 H. Bar     42.44    111   402
    115 M. Cha     20.39    111   401
    115 M. Cha     3.616    111   402
    116 Q. Xyz     20.39    111   401
    116 Q. Xyz     3.61     111   402
```

Now what I want is to convert the EmployeeInfo column values to column names

```
   114 H. Bar  115 M. Cha  116 Q. Xyz  RowID
     73.71       20.39       20.39      401
     42.44       3.616       3.61       402
```

The number of rows in EmployeeInfo can vary and hence I need a dynamic pivot function.

Any clues..?

Comment: Dynamic pivoting is the answer.I have given an answer for a similar kind of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279442/sql-values-of-rows-as-columns/12280245#12280245. Try to implement the concept in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
create table #t table(EmployeeInfo varchar(20),  Hours float, UnitID int, RowID int)
insert into #t
SELECT  CONVERT(varchar, TS.StaffID) + CHAR(13)  
        + SUBSTRING ( TS.GivenName, 1 , 1 ) + '.' + CHAR(13)  
        + TS.Surname AS EmployeeInfo, SH.Hours,ts.UnitID,sh.RowID 
         FROM dbo.tbl_TimesheetStaff AS TS 
         Left OUTER JOIN 
         dbo.tbl_StaffHours AS SH ON 
         SH.ActivityUnitID = TS.ActivityUnitID 
         AND Sh.StaffID=ts.StaffID 
         WHERE TS.UnitID=1 



DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(EmployeeInfo)  
                    from #t 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
        ,1,1,'') 

set @query = 'SELECT RowID,  ' + @cols + '   
                from #t 
            pivot  
            ( 
                MAX([Hours]) 
                for Code in (' + @cols + ') 
            ) p ' 
print(@query) 
execute(@query)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Although there is one problem, It's adding an extra row of NULL data in the beginning